# .NET Core 3 - SmtpClient fails in MVC project with PublishTrimmed=true

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, csproj

Specifics:

- dot net core 3 mvc project using SmtpClient
- publishing as single file, trimmed (PublishTrimmed true in csproj file)

Steps: 
Create new dotnetcore 3 project:

```sh
dotnet new mvc
```

In HomeController.cs, add a blank SmtpClient command under Index():

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
            {
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Modify csproj file for single file,trimmed,output runtime.
csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Publish command:

```sh
dotnet publish
```

Run, then navigate to /

**Error message:**

```sh
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
at PubTrimmedSmtpIssue.Controllers.HomeController.Index()
```

**If I remove or switch PublishTrimmed to false in csproj, the project runs properly.**

Any ideas as to why PublishTrimmed is causing errors?

Comment: Are you using System.Net.Mail or MailKit? I do know that System.Net.Mail has been deprecated by Microsoft.

Comment: Indeed, it has been deprecated.  Thank you for the information, I will look into using MailKit moving forward, but still leaving this open because SmtpClient is still part of the core and dn standard frameworks.

Comment: @R.StackUser I see `System.Net.Mail` has not been deprecated. It was a bug in the document. https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-api-docs/issues/2986

Comment: Thank You, for clarifying that. Not sure it is part of your issue. I hope you find a solution to your question.

Comment: @TanvirArjeI, the microsoft docs state it's obsolete: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Ryan Condron I have retooled my methods to use MailKit, and it works flawlessly.  Will leave this issue open in case anyone has answers to the original question.

Comment: i wouldn't call smptclient a part of the frameworks considering it is deprecated. I don't see the point of keeping a question open that asks why a deprecated library isn't working right.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the linker that it fails to detect the right dependency here. You might consider reporting this to Microsoft via GitHub, and also force the linker to keep this type from trimming. Hints can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-core-3-0#assembly-linking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the trimmer is trimming too much in your case.

You can customise the trimming behaviour in the csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.Net.Mail" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed the original issue.

Comment: Great. You should probably still report it on e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx to make sure it gets a bit of visibility for the team who is working on making the runtime more linker-friendly. Even if it would be marked as a duplicate of something else.